# $(“#request-brochure”).validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has got me baffled. I'm sure the solution is obvious, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

All of the files are getting included correctly, and in the right order. I tried just removing the validation completely, just to see what would happen, and then started getting:

**jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function**

...but only on this one page.

Can anyone offer any insights?

The page is at http://www.hotspring.co.nz/request-info/

Comment: Why are you including two different versions of jquery?

Comment: @davin: I believe this is the problem.

Comment: @davin Because I haven't had enough caffeine today apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading two different versions of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--...-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.hotspring.co.nz/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
```

One of them ends up as `$()` and doesn't have validate installed, the other ends up as `jQuery()` and does have validate installed; in particular, `$()` ends up as jQuery 1.5.2 and `jQuery()` ends up as 1.4.4. Open up a JavaScript console on your site and look at these:

```
$.fn.jquery      // This will say 1.5.2
jQuery.fn.jquery // This will say 1.4.4
```

The solution is to just include one jQuery library.

Comment: That was it. I forgot that Wordpress also loads jQuery. I'm still baffled as to why it was working before, but it's fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure nothing else is competing for the "$" object? A lot of toolkits use that and that can cause a lot of issues with jQuery and its plugins. [Experiment with this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and see if that helps you.